# Image Quality distort when minimize the height and width of bitmap

Tags: android

I have a `bitmap` downloaded from internet and now i want to decrease the height and width of bitmap without losing the quality of `bitmap`. How to achieve this.

This is way for downloading bitmap from internet.

```
URL url_1 = null;
try {
    url_1 = new URL(vmImageUrl);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_1.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.v("Error while downloading bitmap from url", e.getMessage());
```

I have scaled like this.

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, convertDpToPixel(140, context), convertDpToPixel(35, context), false);
```

This method convets dp unit to equivalent device specific value in pixels.

```
public static int convertDpToPixel(float dp,Context context)  
{
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = (int) (dp * (metrics.densityDpi/160f));
    return px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set this.

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, convertDpToPixel(140, context), VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(35, context), true);
```

instead of

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, convertDpToPixel(140, context), VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(35, context), false);
```

Its give smoother edges & clear of bitmap. Now its working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Use `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` to get a smaller bitmap.

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(YOUR_FILE, opts);
```

Comment: i want to give the height and width of new bitmap..here i can not

Comment: Yes, the output bitmap has the same aspect ratio with the original bitmap, and the output.width = 1/inSampleSize * original.width. But how can you keep the quality of bitmap without keeping its aspect ratio.

Comment: i want to specify the widht and height of bitmap like we do using  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(140, context), VirtualMirrorActivity.convertDpToPixel(35, context), false);

Comment: If the width and height you specified have a very different aspect ratio with the original value, you are distorting the image and it will certainly lose quality.

Answer (score -2):

you need 2 Rect,

```
Rect src = new Rect();
Rect dst = new Rect();
```

then u can set the src for the current image,

```
src.set(0,0,imgWidth,imgHeigth);
```

then then the required size

```
dst.set(startX,startY,endX,endY);
```

Note: startX and startY will be the destination coordinates on the screen
and ur image will be drawn u to the endX endY coordinate.
and draw ur bit man with Canvas

```
Canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapFile, src, dst, null);
```

Comment: My question is diff not draw bitmap on canvas i need quality bitmap after decreasing height and width..

Comment: ok my bad, u can set the preferred RGB for the bitmap before loading
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
   bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);